# ANTLR4 subrule ambiguity

Tags: performance, antlr4, ambiguity

Here is simple grammar that illustrates the problem of a real, more complicated grammar:

```
grammar test;

WHITESPACE : (' ' |'\t'|'\r')+? -> skip;
fragment WORD_CHAR: [a-zA-Z_0-9];
WORD: WORD_CHAR+;
PUNCTUATION: ','|'_'|'-'|'('|')';

plain_phrase: (WORD | PUNCTUATION)+;
quoted_phrase: '"' plain_phrase '"';
phrase: plain_phrase|quoted_phrase;
sentence: phrase+ '.';
document: (sentence|'\n'+)+ EOF;
```

It works as expected combining words into phrases and dividing sentences to quoted and unquoted phrases, but profiler of ANTLR4 plugin in IntellJ IDEA reports ambiguity on every word. For example, applying the rule `document` to input "One  two three." reports the following alternatives at the second word:

[image: Plugin ambiguity image]

In the real grammar the `plain_phrase` rule takes lots of parsing time. Is there a way to resolve this ambiguity and improve performance of parser?

Comment: You're taking closures of closures of closures. Of course, it's ambiguous. Try `grammar test; WHITESPACE : (' ' |'\t'|'\r')+? -> skip; fragment WORD_CHAR: [a-zA-Z_0-9]; WORD: WORD_CHAR+;PUNCTUATION: ','|'_'|'-'|'('|')'; plain_phrase: WORD | PUNCTUATION; quoted_phrase: '"' plain_phrase+ '"'; phrase: plain_phrase|quoted_phrase; sentence: phrase+ '.'; document: (sentence|'\n')+ EOF;`

Comment: Well, right, your grammar removes the ambiguity, but divides the sentence into multiple phrases each one word length, while the original combined words into single phrase. If I gather words under a single rule as below, the ambiguity returns. Also, isn't that exactly the purpose of subrule: take closures ... `grammar test1;

WS : (' ' |'\t'|'\r')+? -> skip;
fragment WCHR: [a-zA-Z_0-9];
WORD: WCHR+;
PNCTN: ','|'_'|'-'|'('|')';

p_el: WORD | PNCTN;
plain: p_el+;
quoted: '"' plain '"';
phrase: plain|quoted;
sentence: phrase+ '.';
document: (sentence|'\n')+ EOF;`

Comment: "but divides the sentence into multiple phrases":  well, you  asked why the ambiguity arose and a possible way to improve  the grammar. Your new  requirement  was not part of your question. The fact there is an ambiguity  is clear after  kaby76's comment, right?

Comment: Right, I updated question to make it clear what was expected from the grammar

Comment: In your grammar, there is no way to distinguish when a `phrase` ends and another `phrase` begins. When the input is just a collection of N-words followed by `.`, there are 2^(N-1) derivations (e.g., `a b c d e` each phrase is a single WORD, `(a b) c d e`, `a (b c) d e`, a two-WORD phrase and three single-WORD phrases in various combinations, etc). What you could try is to make the outer closure non-greedy using the `+?`-operator. But I don't know if that will solve the performance issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this "ambiguity" is simply an artifact of the rule that gathers `WORD`s and `PUNCTUATION` (I know, duh).  Gathering necessarily implies the different possibilities.  ANTLR will always use the 1st one.  Are you experiencing an actual performance issue, or just trying to eliminate all ambiguities proactively for performance.  You can't have them combined, AND have no ambiguities.  You'll have to make a choice.  In general, I've not seen performance issues from this sort of ambiguity, and combining them will definitely give an easier tree to deal with.

Comment: @MikeCargal For the original grammar, Antlr4.9.3 creates a flat tree where a phrase contains a single word. On my machine, for an 8k word input, C#, parse time is 130k tokens per sec, 0.05s, very fast. Similar for Java. So maybe it's not a perf issue.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to proactively eliminate ambiguities for performance, as at this time the grammar is not yet completely defined and will grow in complexity through the life of the project. I thought this case would be easy to fix. Thank you both for explanation, looks like I should live with it for time being.